# How can I import a text file of frames and shape IDs (from Adobe Character Animator) and auto apply them to matching shape keys in Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, import

I'm trying to take lipsync info generate by Adobe Character Animator and apply it to shape keys in Blender.

Adobe Character Animator will let me copy its generated lipsync information from the timeline and paste it into a text document.

The result looks like this:

```
Adobe After Effects 8.0 Keyframe Data

    Units Per Second    25

    0   0
    79  11
    86  7
    89  0
    105 1
    111 6
    115 0
    127 2
    129 11
    137 9
    139 1
    142 6
    146 6
    152 11
    178 3

End of Keyframe Data
```

The first digit on each line is the frame number of the animation and the second is the mouth shape layer (so 0 is neutral mouth layer, 11 is a Wuh mouth layer etc.)

If I somehow assign my mouth shape keys in Blender to match the ones from Character Animator (0 is neutral, 11 is Wuh etc) Is there a way to put this into a format/script where I could:

1. bring this data into Blender,
2. and get blender to automatically go to each frame in the list in order and set that shape key to 1 and all others to 0 for each of the lines in the list?
3. Hold each shape key until the frame it changes to the next one. (so in example mouth shape 0 holds from frame 0 to frame 78, mouth shape 11 holds from frame 79 until frame 85 etc)

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you looked at the current lipsync addons. The data of most eg Papagayo is not much different, frame : phoneme pairs.

Comment: I've had a look at them a bit. I use Character Animator for a lot of other projects and it's usually rock solid, super fast and and very easy to adjust.  I was hoping if there was an easy way to bring that info in then it would help keep my current lipsyncing workflow, but you may be right, that I will have to look at an existing system. 
I guess that there might be a way to paste that Adobe data into Papagayo and hijack it! Thanks!